# What year is it in Spider-Man: Homecoming?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, captain-america-civil-war, spider-man-homecoming

"Avengers" took place in 2012. The start of "Spider-Man: Homecoming" was right after the Battle of New York. In "Civil War", in 2016, it's been 8 years since Iron Man was outed as Tony Stark.  Captain America says he was in the ice for 65 years. That means he was iced in 1946.

Comment: It was assumed by 2017 that MCU films take place during the release year. "CA The First Avenger" was the sole exception at the time.

Comment: Actually, cap went in the ice in '45, and says then that he was in the ice for 70 years. He was just approximating. he was in the ice from 1945- 2012, 67 years. "I went in the ice in '45 right after I met the love of my life. Woke up 70 years later"